# Datebox broken in zk 7 using bootstrap

Tags: java, zk

Need help when i am using datebox in zk 7 bootstrap,datebox position not in right postion how to fix the problem like is showed up in my picture below??

[image]

here is my zul file code :

```
<div> 
        <hlayout width="50%"> 
         <datebox  width="200px"/>         
         <textbox id="txtFind" width="200px" top="10px" />   
         <button id="find"      width="50px" height="25px" src="/img/Find24.png"    tooltiptext="Find Record"/>
        </hlayout>
    </div>
```

Comment: http://zkfiddle.org/sample/3lgom7p/1-stackexchange-question I can't reproduce it with this code alone.  Possible to alter the fiddle and metnioning the exact zk version?

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the width of hlayout:

```
    <hlayout width="70%">
```